# Html tag validation with php

Tags: php, html

I have to write a PHP script which generates an HTML form like in the example below.

It should contain a label, an input text field and a submit button.
The user enters **HTML tag** in the input field (without `<` and `>`).

If the tag is **valid**, the script should print “Valid HTML tag!”, and if it is **invalid** – “Invalid HTML Tag!”.

My question is: is there a function which compares a string with a real and valid html tags? I didn't find anything after long searching. 
Thanks for your attention!

Comment: The question does not specify what it means by “valid HTML tags”. Valid as per which specification? And it asks about tag validity, but it probably meant to ask about tag names only.

Answer (score 2):

No, php doesn't provide you such thing.
But what you can do is make a "whitelist", which contains all valid tags, and then compare the input with each entry in the list.

For example:

```
<?php
$tags= array("html", "head", "body", "div");
if (in_array($input, $tags)) {
    echo "Valid HTML tag!";
}else{
    echo "Invalid HTML Tag!";
}
?>
```

You can find a complete list of HTML tags here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element (Look at the sidebar on the left).

This is propably the fastest and easiest way of doing it, but you might need to update the list everytime a new html standard gets released (which doesn't happen quite often).

If you want to make it **case insensitive**, you only need to use [strtolower()](http://php.net/strtolower):

```
if (in_array(strtolower($input), $tags)) { ... }
```

(Note that the tags within the whitelist also need to be lower case)

Comment: Do however note that this is case-sensitive, which means that "Body" won't pass.

Comment: @Ali: The question never mentioned that it has to be case insenstive. But I updated my anser anyway, since it is really easy to achive.

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but citing w3schools is bad practice, especially when cited for definitions. It is unreliable and non-authoritative.